# Failed to parse the JSON document: Request successfully return 200 response but response body isn't printed in Log file

Tags: java, rest, cucumber, bdd, rest-assured

I got an exception with validating "status": "OK" in the response body of the DeletePlace request. Request is successful with 200 status code but there is no response body in the log file. Console error is pointing to the  Utils line#47. Below is the code & screenshot of the error console pointing error to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMNpV.png)

```
package resources;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class Utils {
    
    public static RequestSpecification req;
    public RequestSpecification requestSpecification() throws IOException
    {
        if (req==null)
        {
        PrintStream log = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("logging.txt"));
        req = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri(getGlobalValue("baseUrl")).addQueryParam("key", "qaclick123")
                .addFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.logRequestTo(log))
                .addFilter(ResponseLoggingFilter.logResponseTo(log))
        .setContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
        return req;
        }
        return req;
    }
    
    public static String getGlobalValue(String key) throws IOException
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\Eclipse-Workspace\\RestAssuredAPIFramework\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\global.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }
    
    public String getJsonPath(Response response, String key)
    {
        String resp = response.asString();
        JsonPath js = new JsonPath(resp);
        return js.get(key).toString(); //Error line
    }

}
```

Please help me out and let me know if any other information is required.

I've tried creating getJsonPath method again and all possible fixes I got from various articles but not able to resolved this. I'm expecting the test to execute without any error.

Comment: response body from the DeletePlace request might be empty, maybe checking if the response body is empty before trying to extract a value from it would help

Comment: @KiranKandel No DeletePlace request is having following body when hit it from postman: {
  "status": "OK"
}

Comment: then maybe try passing resp.body to jsonpath instead?

Comment: still not working

Comment: @deepakthakur it indicates that your response is empty. Use proxy tool to capture request in RA and postman then compare them to find the differences.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` to get your properties, like this :

```
@Value(value = "classpath:your_file.json")
private Resource resource;
```

after you got your file, try to mapping with :

```
public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String json) {
    try {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>(){});
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```